# How can I use gmailapi in angular7

Tags: angular, api, email

I'm using Angular7 project. But I want to notify using email. Can anyone tell how to implement Gmail API inside code? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send post request with attachment and message with sender details to nodejs server and You can use nodemailer or email js to send/notify

```
https://nodemailer.com/about/
https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs
```

Comment: @Mokkasoru https://codeburst.io/sending-an-email-using-nodemailer-gmail-7cfa0712a799

Comment: @Mokkasoru install a expressjs server and please go through they have 
 mentioned all the steps clearly. https://www.codementor.io/joshuaaroke/sending-html-message-in-nodejs-express-9i3d3uhjr